# Change border height

Tags: css, border

I've a div with after border with triangle shape, but I want to reduce the height of the triangle . [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13uwb7kb/)

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #88b7d5;
}
.box:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: #88b7a1;
    border-width: 100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Reduce the height of the triangle or the square?

Comment: the height of triangle @VytasBradunas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `border-top-width` of triangle to any value you like:

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #88b7d5;
}
.box:after {
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-top-color: #88b7a1;
 border-width: 100px;
    border-top-width: 50px;
 margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a this to the .box:after definition:

```
border-top-width: 50px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/13uwb7kb/